# Car adapters (12V -> 5V) in parallel

Tags: dc-dc-converter, automotive, adapter

Am wondering if there are any risks involved in putting two (5V) car cigarette lighter adapters in parallel. They will be part of a setup replacing the car stereo, so will be connected to the "ignition" wire, not the cigarette lighter.

The two adapters I have are very different in appearence, and one of them is rated 1.5A, the other one unknown. I need something like 2.5-3A.

I assume both of them contain surge protection, which is one reason for using them.

Any reason for not two in parallel?

Clarification: parallel as in output sides connected.

Comment: If one is "unknown" how would you know if it's capable of delivering the power you need?

Comment: @Finbarr: I was planning to find that out empirically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends. If the adapters are powering separate circuits, it should be fine, provided you're not exceeding the current rating of the wires.

However, connecting the outputs in parallel would not be a good idea, as any voltage difference in their outputs will place more of a load on one, possibly exceeding its rated current. You almost certainly will not be able to safely produce the sum of the two adapters' currents, as the weaker one will likely drop its output voltage, leaving the other adapter with most of the load. In this case, you're much better off buying a single large supply that can handle the current you need.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking. But is it likely this will be a problem? They are supposedly both producing 5V.

Comment: The car stereo fuse is 8-20A (there are three; I am not sure which one it is).

Comment: @TomasBy yes, they produce “5V”, but that means one may produce 4.9v unloaded and one may produce 5.1v. Also, as you increase the load, the voltage tends to sag, and will likely change at different rates on the different power supplies

Comment: But isn't that fairly small differences? You say above that one would have "most of the load"... (I'm asking honestly, my intuition on this topic is weak.)

Comment: @TomasBy If both adapters initially start out at 5V, but one adapter drops faster than the other, the adapter with the higher voltage will take most of the load, and the other one will only output as much current as needed to match the voltage of the higher voltage power supply. So even if both supplies are rated at 1A, by the time you get to 1A total current, you may find that one supply is supplying 90% of the current. In that case, you'd be unable to draw 2A of current, even though in theory it'd be possible

Comment: Ok. I thought maybe it would tend to even out.